# Functional Tranformation - Abel equation of the first kind to canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to carry out the above using the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2 but I am a little confused about the equations (2.2). The general form (2.1) is in terms of u (dependent) and $\xi$ (independent) but in (2.2) the transformation E is the integral of functions of $\xi$ with respect to a new variable x, and $E^{2}$ appears in another integral (defining x?) with respect to $\xi$.

$$\frac{du}{d\xi }=f_{3}(\xi)u^{3}+f_{2}(\xi)u^{2}+f_{1}(\xi)u+f_{0}(\xi)$$ (2.1)

Transformations (2.2):
$$x=\int f_{3}E^{2}d\xi$$
$$y=(u+\frac{f_{2}}{3f_3})E^{-1}$$
$$E=exp(\int f_1 -\frac{f_2^{2}}{3f_3})dx$$

I know that I must be missing something really simple, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

transformation E is function of ξ not x it is a typos in the paper, see Polyanin 0.1.5-2 "handbook of exact solutions of ordinary differential equations" This papaer is full of typos and i did not get any luck with applying the solution included, please tell me if you had luck with it.Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I will try their versions of the transformations soon and certainly let you know if it works.